# Which policy to complete an answer made by someone else ?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

What is the general policy for completing an answer from an other user ? Should I prefer to start an other answer, just saying "As user:xxx said, blabbla, BUT I would like to add blabla..." or should I edit the previous answer, with the possibility to severely annoy its author ? After all, that's her/his answer... so is it well accepted to edit the others' answers ?

For instance, part of the answer should be wrong. Should I delete this part by myself, or make a comment to the author ? (I obviously prefer the second option, but the first one, if it become more accepted, could be time saving I believe).

For instance, an answer could be full of doubtful remarks like "I believe that $x=y$... ", but I know this is for sure. Should I edit the answer such that only "$x=y$" appears ?

I believe there are much more possibilities, I'm asking for your experience and knowledge about the edit of someone else's answer.

Answer (score 4):

This has been asked [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28817/178438) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/edit-an-existing-answer-or-incorporate-existing-answer-into-a-new-one) on the main meta. In this case I'll just copy [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129515/178438) over there.

> - If its just a bit of more info (read:a paragraph), add it and leave a comment.
> - If it's a completely new bundle of stuff, but is based on stuff gleaned from the answer, write an addendum answer as described above.
>     Hat it with "This is in addition to @JonSkeet's answer". You may also
>     comment on the original answer and ask the poster to incorporate your
>     answer if s/he wishes--and then delete your answer once the deal is
>     done ([Something smilar could have happened here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28817/178438), though it
>     didn't).
>
> Examples:
>
> [Factors affecting torque and RPM of a motor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22303/factors-affecting-torque-and-rpm-of-a-motor/22317#22317)
>
> [How can one imagine curled up dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/how-can-one-imagine-curled-up-dimensions/23205#23205)
>
> [Penetration versus Frequency](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/penetration-versus-frequency/22134#22134)
>
> [Will an emf be induced across the ends of a stationary metal rod placed in a time-varying magnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23824/will-an-emf-be-induced-across-the-ends-of-a-stationary-metal-rod-placed-in-a-tim/23895#23895)

---

In the case of wrong answers (or parts of answers), leave a comment. Try not to make radical changes in edits -- you can tell the OP in a comment to make them himself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I indeed forgot to check on the SO meta. Sorry for the repeat. Thanks again.

Comment: Even adding a paragraph to an existing answer is something I would consider a radical edit, if it didn't actually come from the OP.